# Why Jenkins not stored data?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I try to configure Jenkins at Unubtu 16.04:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Then, i see at logs:

```
Attempting to dynamic load /var/jenkins_home/plugins/workflow-aggregator.jpi
Started initialization
Listed all plugins
Prepared all plugins
Started all plugins
Augmented all extensions
Loaded all jobs
Completed initialization
Plugin workflow-aggregator:2.3 dynamically installed
```

But, at /var/jenkins_home i cound not found any file.

What should i do to solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: Unless @Alex O fixes your problem, you need to add more info. Include `docker info` and `docker version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ensure that `/your/home` is accessible by the `jenkins` user.

```
ls -la /your/home
```

You can create a `jenkins` user  with uid `1000` and then grant its ownership.

```
groupadd -g 1000 jenkins
useradd -d "/your/home" -u 1000 -g 1000 -m -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for files in `/your/home`.

The path `/var/jenkins_home` is only valid inside the container, and maps to `/your/home` on your host.